# Laravel 3 reset orders on click of report

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-3

I have a PDF object created when I click generate orders. I want to (after the results have been shown of all of the orders) remove all the orders in the table. I tried this in the routes but it does not work?

```
//used to reset the orders in database
Route::filter('reset', function()
{
//once rendered the report remove all of the orders from db
DB::query("DELETE FROM orders");
});
```

The get request for the report is as follows:

```
Route::get('report', array('as' => 'report', 'after' => 'reset','uses' => 'admin@report'));
```

How would I go about doing this, because obviously the script exits before when it creates the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
DB::table('orders')->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a route filter I decided to place it after the outputting of the PDF, should of thought about it more.

```
        $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','en');

        //set it to full page
        $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

        //write the html from the view 'report' and attach the $data array
        $html2pdf->WriteHTML(View::make('documents.report', $data));

        //output the pdf so the user can view
        $html2pdf->Output('orders.pdf');

        //delete all the orders
        DB::table('orders')->delete();
```

It now removes all orders after every request of the pdf